# inserted values on updated database are not correct - MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc

im trying to update the values of columns from the same row in my database.

Here is my code:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = @"Update Content Set Des='@Des', Sc='@Sc' Where ID_Img=@Id_Img";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Des", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Des"].Value = model.Des;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Sc"].Value = model.Sc;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_Img", SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Id_Img"].Value = model.Id_Img;

                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     cn.Close();
                }
}
}
```

the code works and i get no error, but when i check in my database the values inserted are @Desc and @Sc and not properly the values which comes from form in my view.

I have set a breakpoint and check which values are in the variables all off them have the correct one..

What im doing wrong?

Someone can give me a hand pls?

Comment: how are you sure if you are not getting any errors? after the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` you are not doing any error trapping / handling wrap that code around a `try{}catch{}` also have you debugged the code to make sure the expected values are being passed to those 2 parameters..?

Comment: try without quotes `Des=@Des, Sc=@Sc `

Comment: im sure.. i have check all values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't wrap your parameters in quotes in the actual query.  Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Update Content Set Des=@Des, Sc=@Sc Where ID_Img=@Id_Img";
```

The parameters are smart enough to know if they need to be wrapped in quotes or not based on their data types.

Comment: Yep.. This is it... damn... Thank you very much David.. Never thought that this was the problem.. @Stephan: you have right for what you have purposed